# how to insert MathMl Language into the mysql database column

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, mathml

I want to create online math quiz and all questions and answers and correct answer via using `MathMl Language`. But how do i insert MathMl Language into the mysql database?
i need to make `Quadratic Formula or Equation` using Mathml Language and store into the database?

what kind of function help to insert mathml language?

**Example Of MathML Language**

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
  <mrow>
    <mi>x</mi>
    <mo>=</mo>
    <mfrac>
      <mrow>
        <mo>&#x2212;</mo>
        <mi>b</mi>
        <mo>&#xB1;</mo>
        <msqrt>
          <mrow>
            <msup>
              <mi>b</mi>
              <mn>2</mn>
            </msup>
            <mo>&#x2212;</mo>
            <mn>4</mn>
            <mi>a</mi>
            <mi>c</mi>
          </mrow>
        </msqrt>
      </mrow>
      <mrow>
        <mn>2</mn>
        <mi>a</mi>
      </mrow>
    </mfrac>
  </mrow>
</math>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the MathML as simple text/string and insert it into the MySQL database. What programming language are you using?